# C Segmentation Fault from function that returns the maximum of an array

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, max

I just have a function that finds out the maximum value of an array of integers, but I get a **segmentation fault**, which I can't find because the compiler doesn't show me the line of the error.

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Funktion ermittelt den größten Wert eines Arrays
int groesstesElement(int **arrayPointer){
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (*arrayPointer[i]>max) {
            max = *arrayPointer[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int array[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int *ptr = array;
    int z = groesstesElement(&ptr);
    printf("%d\n", z);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use macOS and VSC.

Comment: A segmentation fault is a runtime error.  The compiler won't know about these.

Comment: Debugger..........

Comment: The root of the problem is that you use pointer to pointer for no reason what-so-ever. That in turn made your code needlessly complex and you ended up writing a precedence bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, array indexing `[]` has higher precedence than pointer de-referencing `*`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Some parentheses fix the segfault.

```
if ((*arrayPointer)[i]>max) {
    max = (*arrayPointer)[i];
}
```

Comment: @chrizzla No, it's not. Check also my answer. (this answer anyway is concise, accurate, and deserves to be the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

Due to the operators precedence, with

```
*arrayPointer[i]
```

you are telling your program:

> Take the *i-th* element of the array `arrayPointer` and dereference it.

But `arrayPointer` is a pointer to `int *`, so all you get is the address of `ptr` (the `int **` pointer defined from main) with an offset. When you finally dereference it you are likely accessing an invalid address, causing segmentation fault.

As already suggested by the main answer, the fix is done using parenthesis in order to apply the operators in the order you want:

```
(*arrayPointer)[i]
```

### Secondary issues in the code

Even though with the correction above the program won't crash anymore, it **won't work**. Searching through the array with the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

you won't include the last item in the search (index 3), skipping precisely the index that, in your example, contains the maximum value. You probably meant `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)` or `for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)`.

Anyway, using *magic numbers* in the code (in this case the dimension of the array) is considered **bad practice**. A better solution would have been using a `#define`, but an even better solution would have been passing to the function the size of the array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 4

//Funktion ermittelt den größten Wert eines Arrays
int groesstesElement(int *arrayPointer, unsigned int arrSize){
    int max = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (arrayPointer[i]>max) {
            max = arrayPointer[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int array[ARR_SIZE]={1,2,3,4};
    int z = groesstesElement(array, ARR_SIZE);
    printf("%d\n", z);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note how **there's no need to use a double pointer** anymore.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. Helped me a lot to get a better understanding about what is going on in my code.I actually used the double pointer just to get used to them and see how they work.